# Find statistical correlations in a relational database

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining, statistics

I have a large SQL database of associations between state features and a reward metric. e.g.

```
A ^ B ^ C ^ D ^ Action(E) => 0.1
F ^ G ^ W ^ D ^ Action(R,P,H) => 0.9
A ^ T ^ U ^ Y ^ Action(A,S) => 0.2
```

My features may be discrete, continuous, or nominal. I'm trying to find a set of rules or patterns that can be used to maximize the reward metric. What would be the best tools to use to mine this data in order to find the strongest statistical correlations (preferably written in or accessible from Python)?

Comment: Did you look up PyBrain already ?

Comment: @Thomas, I'm somewhat familiar with PyBrain, and as I understand it, it's a general machine-learning library and robotics control framework. However, I don't believe it has any SQL database support, nor large-scale statistical analysis functions. Am I mistaken? How you think it can help with this task?

Comment: Well, what I would try doing would be to use PyBrain's machine-learning capabilities, on a smaller dataset if needed, which might provide you with input-output relationships, you can then try and maximize the output that way. I fear I won't be able to help much more though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a well-established family of techniques directed to precisely to the use case presented in your Question. Given the pedigree and braod selection of libraries implementing these techniques, they are not well known even to many data analysts.

This class of techniques is called ***Frequent Itemsets*** (or Frequent Itemset Learning); the terms  ***Association Rules*** and Market Bakset Analysis are also used but the latter is much less common. (As an aside, perhaps the vague-sounding names contribute to their relative obscurity).

The first sentence of ***arules*** background Docs (*arules* is an R Package implementing Association Rules) :

> *Mining frequent itemsets and association rules is a popular and
>   well-researched method for discovering interesting relations between
>   variables in large datasets.*

Taxonomically, AR/FI is an *unsupervised* machine learning technique, that according to HTF is a simplification of "bump hunting" or "mode finding"

In any event, those two terms--used either by themselves or together are the best inital query terms for Web searches. You will find Wikipedia entries for both terms; the one for [Association Rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) is a good high-level overview, but sufficiently detailed for a programmer. So those two terms describe the technique; "Apriori" and "Eclat" are the two most widely used implementations of the original Association Rules algorithm, which was originally devleoped at IBM Almaden Research.

To use *apriori*, you pass in the database fields that you want the algorithm to test for association; you also pass in a threshold association--aka *support level*. i usuaully chose 5% then tune it in one direction or the other until i get the number of rules that i want (the higher the support level, the fewer rules returned).

What *apriori* returns is the association rules themselves.

If you want a python library to do AR/FI, then [**Orange**](http://orange.biolab.si/) is the only one that i know of (there could be others). (Orange has a GUI, as you probably know, but it has a nice scripting interface for python). I have never used Orange but i just had a brief look at its Association Rules module and and it seems to be implemented similarly to the AR libraries i have personally used. The [tutorial](http://orange.biolab.si/doc/ofb/assoc.htm) (in python) i thought was very good.

My recommendation might be to access R's strong support for AR/FI via Python using the R bindings, [RPy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html).

R is the only language/platform have used for *Association Rules*, and i have all of the five AR/FI libraries a fair amount. For my first AR/FI project, my choice of R had nothing to do with the availability or quality of the AR/FI libraries, but rather with the simple-to-use relational database drivers (for MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite); now there are also drivers/bindings for the most commonly used NoSQL transaction databases like MongoDB and CouchDB. The MySQL drivers/bindings allowed me to connect to my database via R, and feed the data directly to the *apriori* algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem of "trying to find a set of rules or patterns that can be used to maximize the reward metric" sounds a lot like [Reinforcement Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning). If after preforming an action in a given state you transition to another new state and you are looking for an optimal policy (i.e. what action to take when in state x) then your problem is basically exactly that of Reinforcement Learning. If the transition probabilities (if i do action a while in state x then the probability of transitioning to state y) are known then you may want to look into [MDPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_Decision_Process), if you do not know the transition probabilities then look into [Q-Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Learning). Note, depending on your state space you may need to be clever to get Reinforcement Learning to scale, but if it's 4D then you're probably OK. While I do not know of a python implementation for Reinforcement Learning, there should be one out there. You may also want to check out [Dr. Ng's Lectures](http://academicearth.org/courses/machine-learning) on RL.

Comment: RL is exactly what I'm doing, but traditional RL algorithms are quite horrible at these types of large statistical domains. For example, each "state" in my domain is likely unique, making modeling the literal transition statistics useless. Therefore, I have to do some state reduction...which basically I'm asking about.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear by what you mean by "statistical domains" and what is meant by each state being probably unique. If you mean the state space and that your data set only contains one sample for each state then I think a reasonable thing to try to do in order to build transitional probabilities is to learn a sequential model like an HMM that can generalize with the given data. An HMM will achieve a state reduction that is aware of the transition mechanisms. The later lectures from Dr. Ng on RL mention several techniques to deal with high dimensional state spaces, which may be of use.